# Array of String to Date format conversion in Java

Tags: java, java-me

I have a String in which dates are there. I want this String to be Stored in another date Array after conversion and then convert this into calendar.

```
st_date = (Date)formatter.parse(startDt);
```

Currently I am using above function but this  works only for String and not for array.

Below code is not working. Can anybody give the reason??

```
Date holiday[]=null;
Calendar holidays[]=null;
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)      
   {    
     holiday[i] = formatter.parse(holid[i]);
     holidays[i] = Calendar.getInstance();       
     holidays[i].setTime(holiday[i]);
   }
```

Kindly give the solution as soon as possible.

Comment: Please write java code in {} code tag. When you post the question

Comment: Even better, indent four spaces.  Check the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Can I make a suggestion....think of better names for your variables.  You have three arrays in the above code holid, holiday, and holidays.  Someone reading it will have no idea what each one is meant to contain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing `holid` is a `String[]` containing your formatted dates?

Your array initialisation is wrong. You have to do it like this:

```
Date[] holiday = new Date[holid.length];
Calendar[] holidays = new Calendar[holid.length];
```

Comment: I corrected my answer. Of course you shouldn't hard-code `5` in your array constructors, but take the length of your existing array `holid`. Since you hard-coded `5` yourself in your loop `for(int i=0;i<5;i++)`, I assumed you already know these facts somehow...